# JavaScript variable is not getting assigned - Paypal Blank Screen on withdrawal bugfix

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, paypal

It's been an year, still Paypal withdrawal page crashes for me and Paypal doesn't know why. So I decided to dig in.

Problem:

**Line 185:** A variable called `fiType` is created.

**Line 189:** If expression is evaluated to `true`

**Line 190:** `fiType` should be set to `cards`. But it's undefined. Why?

[image]

I'm looking for a way to manually set this, but Chrome debuggers saving option doesn't save the typescript. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `fiType` defined anywhere else or typed differently (special characters that look the same)?

Comment: @JavaScript: I checked. `fiType` is a local variable and there is no character wise difference.

Comment: fiType gets defined after 190 executes, doesn't it? So really the important question is what it's set to at 195. Is that when it errors for you? Can you post the error if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome seems not saving the local changes you make for **TypeScript + WebPack bundled** sites.

You can override file that throws the exception (https://www.paypalobjects.com/..../appBundle.js) with the extensions:

- [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii?hl=en)
- [Always Disable Content Security policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-disable-content-se/ffelghdomoehpceihalcnbmnodohkibj/related?hl=en)

and try to patch the issue locally.

You will also need to start Chrome with the flags `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="ChromeProfile"`

Comment: It throws an exception because my currency has not been added to a part of the frontend code. I managed to override the issue with Resource Override. Thanks!